# How do I insert html tag inside of script?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

How do I insert html tag inside of script?

Here is how I'm trying:

```
document.Tick.Clock.value=hours+"<span>:</span>"+minutes+":"
```

Original:

```
document.Tick.Clock.value=hours+":"+minutes+":"
```

Comment: Do you have a problem?

Comment: Hint: Attributes cannot have tags inside of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your html element has a value property I assume it's an input. If it is then you can set the value including html tags:

```
<input type="text" id="mytext" />
<script>
document.getElementById("mytext").value="<p>helo</p>"
</script>
```

If your html element is not an input element then you should set innerHTML:

```
<div id="mytext"></div>
<script>
document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML="<p>helo</p>"
</script>
```

Comment: My problem was solved by using innnerHTML.. Thanks HMR